# How to determine number of elements with a non-empty property in Python in a collection?

Tags: python

I have the following collection.

```
[
{'propertyA': {},
 'propertyB': 12345,
 'id': 1},
{'propertyA': {},
 'propertyB': 12345,
 'id': 2},
{'propertyA': {},
 'propertyB': 12345,
 'id': 3},
{'propertyA': {'subProperty1': 'x',
               'subProperty2': 'y'},
 'propertyB': 67890,
 'id': 4},
{'propertyA': {'subProperty1': 'x',
               'subProperty2': 'y'},
 'propertyB': 67890,
 'id': 5}
]
```

As you can observe, the first three items have the same `'propertyA'` and `'propertyB'`, but they all have unique IDs. So it is safe to assume that `'propertyA'` and `'propertyB'` are like a bundle, the combination of the two stay consistently.

I want to determine the number of **UNIQUE** items (unique in this case is defined as unique combination of `'propertyA'` and `'propertyB'`) in this array with empty (`{}`) the field `'propertyA'`. In this case, it's 1.

To make myself clearer, let's add another item

```
{'propertyA': {},
 'propertyB': 13579,
 'id': 6},
```

The number of unique items is now two. I understand it is a little confusing, please feel free to ask me to clarify further.

Comment: Doesn't your question boil down to finding the number of unique propertyBs given entries where propertyA is an empty dictionary?

Comment: @zehnpaard yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generator expression to filter collections, and use `set` to get unique elements.

```
print len(set(item['propertyB'] for item in a if item['propertyA']=={}))
```

Comment: Don't you need to put `item['propertyB'] for item in a if item['propertyA']=={}` in a list `[ ]`?

Comment: len() gets the number of elements in any sequence.
set() makes a set from any compatible structure, not only a list.  In this case, the generator sequence is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> len(set(map(lambda x: x["propertyB"] if 'propertyA' == {} else None ,l)))

1
```